# Realm.io 'RLMArray is no longer valid' when deleting an RLMObject that has had children objects

Tags: swift, realm

In my app I keep receiving, 'RLMException', reason: 'RLMArray is no longer valid' while attempting to delete an RLMObject that contains a one-to-many relationship with another RLMObject. For example: 'Task' is the RLMObject which contains an RLMArray 'records' with the type 'Record' RLMObjects within it. The code throwing the error is as follows:

```
public class func deleteTask(#taskName: String, retainRecords: Bool) {
    let realm = Database.getRealm()
    let currentTask = (Task.objectsWhere("name = '\(taskName)'").objectAtIndex(0) as Task)
    let loopCount:UInt = currentTask.records.count

    if (retainRecords) {
        for var i:UInt = 0; i < loopCount; ++i {
            Database.moveRecord(record: (currentTask.records.objectAtIndex(0) as Record), newTask: "Taskless Records")
        }
    } else {
        for var i:UInt = 0; i < loopCount; ++i {
            Database.deleteRecord(record: currentTask.records.objectAtIndex(0) as Record)
        }
    }

    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    realm.deleteObject(currentTask)
    realm.commitWriteTransaction()
}
```

The program throws the exception on the line,

```
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

And the loops are moving or deleting all of the child database objects under the Task before attempting to delete the task. Both moving and deleting the records works properly. Also one last important note, if the task doesn't contain records under it then there is no issue deleting it and no exception thrown.

I appreciate anyone's help, I've been banging my head on a brick wall for this issue.

---

**--New Changes based on the reply from yoshyosh--**

I have since modified my code to the following. I still receive the same error.

```
public class func deleteTask(#taskName: String, retainRecords: Bool) {
    let realm = Database.getRealm()
    let currentTask = (Task.objectsWhere("name = '\(taskName)'").firstObject() as Task)
    let currentRecords = currentTask.records
    let parent = currentTask.parent

    if (retainRecords) {
        let loopCount:UInt = currentTask.records.count

        for var i:UInt = 0; i < loopCount; ++i {
            Database.moveRecord(record: (currentTask.records.firstObject() as Record), newTaskName: "Taskless Records")
        }
    } else {
        realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in
            realm.deleteObjects(currentRecords)
        }
    }

    realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in
        realm.deleteObject(currentTask)
    }
}

public class func moveRecord(#record: Record, newTaskName: String) {
    let realm = Database.getRealm()
    let oldTask = record.parent
    let oldIndex = oldTask.records.indexOfObject(record)
    let newTask = (Task.objectsWhere("name = '\(newTaskName)'")).firstObject() as Task

    realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in
        oldTask.records.removeObjectAtIndex(oldIndex)
        newTask.records.addObject(record)
    }
}

public class func addTask(#name: String, memo: String, time: Double, categoryName: String) {
    let realm = Database.getRealm()
    let parentCategory = (Category.objectsWhere("name = '\(categoryName)'")).firstObject() as Category

    realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in
        let newTask = Task()

        newTask.parent = parentCategory
        newTask.name = name
        newTask.memo = memo
        newTask.timeRemaining = time

        parentCategory.tasks.addObject(newTask)
    }     
}

public class func addRecord(#taskName: String, note: String, timeSpent: Double, date: NSDate) {
    let realm = Database.getRealm();

    let parentTask = Task.objectsWhere("name = '\(taskName)'").firstObject() as Task
    realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in
        let newRecord = Record()

        newRecord.parent = parentTask
        newRecord.note = note
        newRecord.timeSpent = timeSpent
        newRecord.date = date

        parentTask.records.addObject(newRecord)
    }
}
```

If needed I can also add the code used to add new Records and new Tasks to the Database. Yoshyosh I appreciate your comment as it did help me clean up my code, unfortunately the error is still being thrown when deleting a Task.

One strange thing I've notice while testing the app, is that when I try deleting the Task it crashes, but once I open the app again the Task and all Records are deleted.

---

**-- Solution --**

I found that I was looking in the completely wrong spot for the error. it was caused by a TableView View Controller that populated with records from a task that was passed into it. It used an RLMArray to retrieve the recordList from the task and used a notificationToken to reload tableView data.

```
var currentTask:Task!
var recordList:RLMArray!
var notificationToken: RLMNotificationToken?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    recordList = currentTask.records

    notificationToken = RLMRealm.defaultRealm().addNotificationBlock { note, realm in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(self.recordList.count)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return Factory.prepareRecordCell(tableView: tableView, recordList: self.recordList, indexPath: indexPath)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

When I would delete a task from a separate view it would try to reload data using the 'recordsList' RLMArray of a task that was deleted.

After removing the notificationToken and manually reloading tableView data inside the viewWillAppear() function deleting tasks works flawlessly.

Comment: The edits don't really change the delete case, but there could be an issue in the move records part. So i'll investigate that

Comment: Can you help isolate, is it just the delete Task?

Comment: Is this all running on the main thread? Do you have any background threads using this?

Comment: This is all running on the main thread. Also the issue is only with delete Task. I have a similar function to delete Categories which contain Tasks; however, after walking through the steps using breakpoints it all boils down to the delete Task function throwing the exception, while the deleteCategory function behaves properly. If you would like, and of course if it isn't against the stackoverflow rules, I could make a youtube video of the breakpoint walkthrough of the code.

Comment: You could send a small sample project privately to help@realm.io this way I can try different things. deleteTask has many things going on in it. It would be good to know if moveObjects has anything to do with the error it or if we can ignore that and focus on the others.

Comment: While trying to create a small sample project I have finally found what was causing the issue. After testing the database in it's own project it worked properly. So I tried it with a tableView how I had mine setup and found no issue. Finally I tracked it to a notifcationToken I was using in a completely different view controller that was reloading the tableView data in the controller. While trying to reload the tableView data it was trying to directly access the RLMArray of a Task that was passed into it previously. Unfortunately this was the same task that was already deleted.

Comment: Ah ok great. That's the tough thing with Xcode, it feels very unhelpful when it comes to debugging. Glad that you were able to find the solution! And don't worry about the wild goose chase, they can be quite tasty for dinner ;). Good luck with the rest of the app and let us know if you run into any other issues with using Realm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your particular case, you would need to show more of your code where deleteRecord is happening. I've tried to reproduce your case as best as possible but everything has deleted fine using the code below:

```
    let currentTask = Task.allObjects().firstObject() as Task
    let currentRecords = currentTask.records
    let loopCount = currentRecords.count

    for var i:UInt = 0; i < loopCount; i++ {
        realm.transactionWithBlock({ () -> Void in
            var recordToDelete = currentTask.records.objectAtIndex(0) as Record
            realm.deleteObject(recordToDelete)
        })
    }

    realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in
        realm.deleteObject(currentTask)
    }
```

I think an easier way to delete all relevant objects is like this:

```
    let currentTask = Task.allObjects().firstObject() as Task
    let currentRecords = currentTask.records

    // Delete Task and records that are connected to it
    realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in
        realm.deleteObjects(currentRecords)
        realm.deleteObject(currentTask)
    }
```

Here's a simple way to update your task with the other records. This code is missing the part where you update the parent of these records though

```
let currentTask = Task.objectsWhere("name = %@", "First task").firstObject() as Task
let currentRecords = currentTask.records
let newFetchedTask = Task.objectsWhere("name = %@", "New Task").firstObject() as Task
realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in
    newFetchedTask.records.addObjects(currentRecords)
    currentTask.records.removeAllObjects()
}
```

Feel free to post more code to debug your particular case

Comment: I have updated the question based on your answer. I no longer use Database.deleteRecord(), so I have only included Database.moveRecord(). I have also added the functions used to add new records and new tasks.

Comment: I really appreciate your help yoshyosh, thank you. I learned useful debugging methods from your comments and suggestions as well as a cleaner way to delete objects using Realm. I also apologize for sending you on a wild goose chase through code that wasn't even causing the problem. Thanks again.